# msdeploy stop working, getting error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Tags: iis, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I am using msdeploy to deploy codes to dev server.  this morning it stops working. and I am getting ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN. nothing changed, at least not that I know of.

abc\jqin, this user is a domain account, its a local admin. why am I still getting ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

> Deploy:     "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
>   -verb:sync -source:package="C:\NetBuild\Packages\IRViewerSvc\IRViewerSvc.zip" -dest:iisApp=IRViewerSvc,computerName=tvw-irwebsvc,username="abc\jqin",password=********
>       Info: Using ID '51e98b9d-456e-4c7e-8f1a-c696c240f431' for
>   connections to the remote server.     EXEC : error Code:
>   ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN [C:\NetBuild\BuildScript\IRViewerSvc.build]
>   More Information: Connected to 'tvw-irwebsvc' using the Web Deployment
>   Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an
>   administrator on 'tvw-irwebsvc'.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
>     Error : The remote server returned an error : (401) Unauthorized.
>   [C:\NetBuild\BuildScript\IRViewerSvc.build]   EXEC : error count: 1.
>   [C:\NetBuild\BuildScript\IRViewerSvc.build]
>     C:\NetBuild\BuildScript\IRViewerSvc.build(71,5): error MSB3073: The
>   command ""C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
>   -verb:sync -source:package="C:\NetBuild\Packages\IRViewerSvc\IRViewerSvc.zip" -dest:iisApp=IRViewerSvc,computerName=tvw-irwebsvc,username="abc\jqin",password=********"
>   exited with code -1.  Done Building Project
>   "C:\NetBuild\BuildScript\IRViewerSvc.build" (deploy target(s)) --
>   FAILED.

Comment: Did the documentation help: https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

Comment: Did you fix it? Care to share how?

Comment: In my case the Admin Users password was expired, resetting the password again solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

Try search mmc and run it click on File add or remove snap-ins, select Local Users and Groups hit ok.
Click on the User uncheck everything and check only Password never expires.

Now go to Groups add new group if it does not exists MSDepSvcUsers, Double click on it and add your User as a member.

Go to Services and restart the Web Deployment Agent Service.

Now try and run your MSDeploy.

I hope this was helpful.
Trosago

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The NetLogon solution posted here didn't work on our AWS EC2 Windows Server 2019 instances because of the following:

```
This computer is configured as a member of a workgroup, not as a member of a domain. The Netlogon service does not need to run in this configuration.
```

The MSDepSvcUsers solution posted here didn't work completely either:

```
[16:19:20]  Error: (2/10/2020 5:19:20 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
[16:19:20]  Error: An error occurred when reading the IIS Configuration File 'MACHINE/REDIRECTION'. The identity performing the operation was 'EC2AMAZ-ABCDEFG\SomeUserName'.
[16:19:20]  Error: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
[16:19:20]  Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

As noted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/083efb2e-d087-4a03-9f6a-662a218cacf8/machineredirection-error?forum=tfsgeneral

Adding the Read & execute and Read access to the folder containing the redirection.config file for the user doing the deploy didn't fix the issue, but adding read permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE user on that same folder did.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered an interment problem where builds were failing with ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.

This was after an OS upgrade to Windows 2016.

The error from MsDeploy was not entirely correct in our situation and we noticed that if the deployment user was remoted onto the server the deploy would complete successfully.

Upon looking at the event log I noticed that there was an error stating that the deployment account failed to logon with a reason 'The NetLogon component is not active.'

Sure enough, the NetLogon service was stopped.  Starting it meant the deployments worked again.